# Passing variable values to awk command in python scripting

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments

I am having below awk command

`awk -F "|" '{ if($132==0 && $123==1) print $145}' abc.dat`

I want to generate awk command by passing values from below variables a,b,c as substitutes instead of numerical values and execute it but it is not happening. It is giving me syntax error. can someone help me in running this awk command using python scripting?

a = 132,

b = 123,

c = 145

I am using python 3.4.4

Comment: Are you using awk or Python? Are you call awk from Python in the shell? Why aren't you just processing the file in Python? Your question is very confusing.

Comment: This requirement requires awk command to run using python scripting 3.4.4. Yes, I have to call awk commend using python. I am doing it for automation

Comment: not very clear what you would like to do...by i guess it's calling shell script inside python? ```import subprocess ; subprocess.run([awk command, some variable...])```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass the column numbers you test and print to awk from some Python code. You would need to do something like this:

```
import subprocess

def awk_by_cols(a, b, c):
    program = "{ if($%d==0 && $%d==1) print $%d}" % (a, b, c)
    return subprocess.check_output(["awk", "-F|", program, "abc.dat"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(awk_by_cols(1, 2, 4).decode())

# Sample data file abc.dat holds:
"""\
0|0|0|0
0|0|1|1
0|1|0|2
0|1|1|3
1|0|0|4
1|0|1|5
1|1|0|6
1|1|1|7
"""
```

Embedding the column numbers in the **program** string can be done using many other methods. I chose the most traditional method - printf-style.